# Installing packages from binary in R 3.4.0

Tags: r, cmd, r-package

I recently updated R to the latest release: 3.4.0. R is installed on a network location `H:/`. Now something weird is happening when I try to install a local binary package:

```
  filename <- paste0("R:/path/independeR_", versions, ".zip")
  install.packages(filename,
                   repos = NULL, type = "source",
                   lib = gsub("\\\\\\\\networkpath/home/[[:alpha:]]*/",
                              "H:/", .libPaths()[1]))
```

Both `H:/` and `R:/` are network locations. In `.libPaths()` the default location is in the `H:/` location, but it shows with the entire network adress. In the call to `install.packages` I substituted this.

The code above fails, with the following output:

```
'\\networkpath\home\JDUB~PN6\DOCU~UZL\R\R-34~TN4.0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"//networkpath/home/JDUB~PN6/DOCU~UZL/R/R-34~TN4.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "H:\Documents\R\R-3.4.0\library" "R:/path/independeR_0.1.8.zip"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘R:/path/independeR_0.1.8.zip’ had non-zero exit status
```

There is two things that surprise me here. The directorynames are all jumbled up (`DOCU~UZL` instead of `Documents` etc), but for some reason  Command promt seems fine with that. The more interesting thing is the following:

When I try to put the command `"//networkpath/home/JDUB~PN6/DOCU~UZL/R/R-34~TN4.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "H:\Documents\R\R-3.4.0\library" "R:/path/independeR_0.1.8.zip"` directly into Command Prompt, the output is very similar:

```
C:\Users\jdubbeldam>"//networkpath/home/JDUB~PN6/DOCU~UZL/R/R-34~TN4.0/b
in/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "H:\Documents\R\R-3.4.0\library" "R:/path/independeR_0.1.8.zip"

'\\networkpath\home\JDUB~PN6\DOCU~UZL\R\R-34~TN4.0' is not recognized as
 an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

For some reason CMD seems to cut off the path to the command halfway through. I guess that this is because the command is too long. When I try the same command, but with `H:/Documents/R/R-3.4.0/bin/x64/R`, the installation goes just fine.

I would like to be able to automatically install this package from a script, so I would like a solution to this problem from within R. Is there a way to get R to use the shorter `H:/Documents/R/R-3.4.0/bin/x64/R`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having problems with updating packages, while searching I found that there is a reported bug affecting getting the timestamps from files in Windows 10:
  https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17261

> Starting in R 3.4.0, file.info *sometimes* returns  for mtime,
>   atime and ctime for directories.  It seems to have something to do
>   with sharing.  This affects functions that use file.mtime like
>   update.packages.
>
> Reproduce:
>
> Try file.info() with a random directory.  If it returns a legitimate
>   file time, open a windows explorer window and navigate to the
>   directory, then run the call again and it will return s.
>
> In some cases it returns s even if the directory is not open (or
>   in the path of an open explorer window), but this is not consistent.

With a comment of Tomas Kalibera:

> Thank you for the report, this is a known bug that has been fixed
>   recently in R-devel

I found that when I closed the file explorer windows the timestamps worked correctly and didn't show up as NA's.
This may be a lead for why your code isn't working.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hmm, I remember seeing the names `mtime` and `ctime` mentioned in error messages when debugging `install.packages`, but didn't quite know what to do with them. 

While this doesn't directly answer the question for how to work around this, it does confirm that it is a bug and that it should be fixed soon-ish.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the following work. However, I think it is extremely ugly, and would still like to see if it is possible to do it someway else.

```
filename <- paste0("R:/path/independeR_", versions, ".zip")

cmd <- file.path(gsub("//networkpath/home/[[:alnum:]]*/", "H:/",
                      gsub("//networkpath/home/[[:alnum:]]*~[[:alnum:]]*/",
                      "H:/", R.home())), "bin/x64/R")

libname <- gsub("\\\\\\\\networkpath/home/[[:alpha:]]*/",
                "H:/", .libPaths()[1])

call <- paste(paste0('"', cmd, '"'), 
              "CMD", 
              "INSTALL", 
              "-l", 
              paste0('"', libname, '"'), 
              "--no-lock",
              paste0('"', filename, '"'), 
              sep = " ")

system(call)
```